# Obfuscate .NET exe after ILMerge merging with .dll dependencies - with ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, .net, dll, obfuscation, ilmerge

I have a product 'prod.exe' which I would like to obfuscate. 'prod.exe' has two dependencies: 'common1.dll' and 'common2.dll'.

I can obfuscate 'prod.exe' fine using ConfuserEx.CLI.exe listing its dependencies in the '.crproj' settings file.

I would also like to obfuscate the dlls 'common1.dll' and 'common2.dll'. Of course if I was to obfuscate these dlls on their own then my product wouldn't be able to reference them, so I need to do it at the same time as I obfuscate the product.

I can't find any obvious way to do this using ConfuserEx, but a potential solution I've attempted is first merging the exe and its dependent dlls using ILMerge and then obfuscating the resulting merged exe with ConfuserEx. Merging works just fine, but when I try to run the merged exe through ConfuserEx I get an error:

> Failed to resolve dependency of prod.exe

This error happens whether or not I provide ConfuserEx paths to the dependent dlls. Although the dependencies are within the binary of prod.exe ConfuserEx can't find them.

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated, whether that's a method to obfuscate an exe and it's dependencies separately or do it on a merged binary like I've attempted.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It appears the ConfuserEx merges dependencies into the target by default removing the need for use of ILMerge.

Comment: What does that mean ?